# Inconsistent Scrapy Xpath Behavior (OS X + Linux)

Tags: python, linux, macos, xpath, scrapy

I'm having trouble with an Xpath selector in Scrapy. Whenever I run the spider on OS X, the selector works as expected; however when I run the same script in Ubuntu 12.04 and Raspbian, the selector doesn't work. I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

The selector is:

```
sel.xpath('//table[@class="times"]')
```

which returns 2 selectors of the tables to me, but when I take it a step further and add in an index to select the 2nd table returned:

```
sel.xpath('//table[@class="times"][2]')
```

OS X returns the 2nd table to me no problem whereas Ubuntu/Raspbian returns nothing: `[]`

I'm at a complete loss as to why this is happening. I've tried my best to replicate the environment (scrapy version 0.20, python 2.7) but I still havent figured it out. For reference, the page I am trying to scrape via shell is

```
scrapy shell "http://washington.dc.gegov.com/webadmin/dhd_431/lib/mod/inspection/paper/_paper_food_inspection_report.cfm?inspectionID=200651&wgdmn=431&wguid=1367&wgunm=sysact"
```

Appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: Does `sel.xpath('//table[@class="times"]')` return the same thing in both environments?

Comment: Yes, both environments return 2 selection objects. Its only when I try and call it by the `[2]` index I get different results

Comment: Did you check if the content of the selection object is also the same in both  environments (ie `sel.xpath('//table[@class="times"]')` is not `[]` in the second case)? Or could it be that the index starts at 0 in the second case, therefore you exceed your selection's length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be cautious when using `//table[@class="times"][2]`: it will select all descendant 2nd children table elements with class "times" of their parent element. So if a node has only 1 child table with class "times", there's not match for this node.

It's not the same as `(//table[@class="times"])[2]` which will give you the 2nd table with class "times" under the root node (which is probably what you want). You could also use `/descendant::table[@class="times"][2]`.

And it's still different from `//table[2][@class="times"]` that selects all descendant table elements that are 2nd child of their parent, AND that have class "times".

See [XPath 1.0 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) on abbreviated syntax `//`:

> NOTE: The location path //para[1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) does not mean the same as the location path /descendant::para[1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev). The latter selects the first descendant para element; the former selects all descendant para elements that are the first para children of their parents.

Let's illustrate that with a `scrapy shell` session

```
paul@wheezy:~$ scrapy shell "http://washington.dc.gegov.com/webadmin/dhd_431/lib/mod/inspection/paper/_paper_food_inspection_report.cfm?inspectionID=200651&wgdmn=431&wguid=1367&wgunm=sysact"

In [1]: sel.xpath('//table[@class="times"][2]')
Out[1]: []

In [2]: sel.xpath('(//table[@class="times"])[2]')
Out[2]: [<Selector xpath='(//table[@class="times"])[2]' data=u'<table class="times" style="font-size:9p'>]

In [3]: sel.xpath('/descendant-or-self::table[@class="times"]')
Out[3]: 
[<Selector xpath='/descendant-or-self::table[@class="times"]' data=u'<table class="times" style="margin-top:1'>,
 <Selector xpath='/descendant-or-self::table[@class="times"]' data=u'<table class="times" style="font-size:9p'>]

In [4]: sel.xpath('/descendant-or-self::table[@class="times"][2]')
Out[4]: [<Selector xpath='/descendant-or-self::table[@class="times"][2]' data=u'<table class="times" style="font-size:9p'>]

In [5]: sel.xpath('/descendant::table[@class="times"][2]')
Out[5]: [<Selector xpath='/descendant::table[@class="times"][2]' data=u'<table class="times" style="font-size:9p'>]

In [6]:
```

Another thing, in your sample page, I see 4 tables that contain "times" in their class attribute:

- `<table class="times" style="margin-top:1...`
- `<table class="times" style="font-size:9p...`
- `<table class="times pt6" cellpadding="0"...`
- `<table class="times fs_10px" style="bord...`

so remember that a `[@class="times"]` predicate means class attribute being exactly "times", not simply containing "times" (you could use `[contains(@class, "times")]` for that)

Comment: That fixed my issue. Adding `(//table[@class="times"])[2]` correctly pulls the nodes that I need, so thanks for that! It's very strange to me that this worked at all on OS X, but not on other *nix environments.